# why shortest distance between two lines is always perpendicular to both the lines

Tags: geometry, vectors

I m new to vectors and lines. I m confused why the shortest distance between two skew lines is always perpendicular between the two lines

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3751172/prove-that-there-exists-a-shortest-distance-between-two-skew-lines)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> The question lulu linked probably answers your question, but another way to consider the issue (that works in very great generality) is to note that if we have a point on each line and the segment between them is _not_ perpendicular one line, we can slide that point along that line to make the angle more nearly a right angle, decreasing the distance between the points.